# RegEx stop at linebreak

Tags: regex

I'm parsing a file and need to extract street and house numbers in separate capture groups.

A file could look like this:

```
Start of String

Straße HNR : example street
 
More example data
```

Currently my expression looks like this:

```
/\s*Straße\s*HNR\s*:\s*(?<loc_street>\D+)(?<loc_streetnumber>\d*\s{0,1}[a-z]*){0,1}/g
```

which matches things like:

```
Straße HNR : example street 1 a
Straße HNR : example street 12
```

correctly. But if I don't have a house number the `(?<loc_street>\D+)` matches just everything until the file ends, but I want to stop at the new line. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this:

```
/\h*Straße\s*HNR\s*:\s*(?<loc_street>[^\d\n]+)(?<loc_streetnumber>\d*\s?[a-z]*)?/g
```

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Qgkfen/1).

One key point is to match only horizontal spaces (`\h`) at the beginning of the line, or it could pick up possible newlines that are before that. `\s` is equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`.

Another point is to make sure you don't match newlines in the `loc_street` group. If you use `\D` you will match anything that is not a digit, including newline. By using `[^\d\n]` you explicitly match anything that is neither a digit nor a newline.

I replaced `{0,1}` with `?`, but that is not important, just personal preference.